# Find the energy-impulse tensor of a fluid of charged dust from the action principle

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, tensor-calculus, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, action

I have the total action given by:

$$S_{tot} = -\frac{1}{16\pi c}\int d\Omega\ F^{\mu \nu}F_{\mu \nu} + \sum_{i=1}^{N}\bigg(-\frac{q}{c}\int dx_i^\mu A_\mu - mc \int ds_i\bigg) \\= \int d\Omega\ \frac{L}{c}$$

where L is the lagrangian density and N is the number of particles in the dust. The particles have same charge q and mass m. I wrote the integral above like an integral in $d\Omega$ and I used the following formula (which is true due to translation simmetry in space-time): $T^{\mu \nu}_{tot} = \partial^\mu A_{\gamma}\frac{\partial L}{\partial( \partial^\nu A_{\gamma})}- \eta^{\mu \nu} L$. Now, I want to find the symmetrized expression of this tensor. To do this, I tried by writing a new tensor in the form:

$$T^{\mu \nu}_{sym} = T^{\mu \nu}_{tot} + \partial_\rho \psi^{\rho \mu \nu}$$

where I want that $\psi^{\rho \mu \nu} = - \psi^{ \mu \rho \nu}$ and so I imposed $T^{\mu \nu}_{sym}-T^{\nu \mu}_{sym} = 0$. So, I found:
$$\partial_\rho (\psi^{\rho \mu \nu}-\psi^{\rho \nu \mu}) = - T^{\mu \nu}_{tot}+T^{\nu \mu}_{tot} \\= \frac{1}{4\pi}\partial_\rho(F^{\mu \rho}A^\nu - F^{\nu \rho}A^\mu) +\frac{1}{c}(J^\mu A^\nu - J^\nu A^\mu)$$ Now, my difficulty is to prove that this last expression could be written in the form $\partial_\rho (\psi^{\rho \mu \nu}-\psi^{\rho \nu \mu})$ with  $\psi^{\rho \mu \nu} = - \psi^{ \mu \rho \nu}$.

I hope that I didn't make any mistake and I apologize in advance for my poor english and if the question isn't well written.